# Reading the USART RX register only when receiving data STM32F4-Discovery Cortex M4

Tags: c, usart

I have a question regarding reading the RX register on my STM32F4-Discovery card when I transmit data through USART from another Discovery card. I only want to read the RX register on card1 once when data has been transmitted from card2, then I want to clear it so I can read the next data that card2 transmits.

What C code could do this for me? What flags can I use? How do I clear the RX register once I have read it?

Answer (score 1):

You must use another register to figure out if `RX` has valid data.

Assuming you use ST's peripheral library (you should!), call the `USART_GetFlagStatus()` function with the `USART_FLAG_RXNE` (which means "RX register not empty") flag.

Or, of course, set up an interrupt to run whenever you receive a byte.

Comment: If I have two cards (Card1(master) and Card2(slave)) connected via USARTx (lets say USART6 for exampe) and I send something using USART6_SendData() from my slave, does it automatically wind up in the RX-register of my master? Does that trigger an interrupt?

Comment: @Flux Yes, assuming the USART on the master is configured identically (same baud rate, byte format, and so on) and (of course) enabled. You probably don't *want* the link to be full-duplex though, it tends to make one's head hurt even more.

Comment: One more question!

When do I enter the USARTx_IRQHandler() function? What interrupts take me there? Systick interrupts from the internal clock?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, download STM32CubeF4 from ST. It contains drivers and example code for the discovery board. Take a look at the UART_TwoBoards_ComIT example project under Examples->UART.

Description in example project:

```
*   This sample code shows how to use STM32F4xx UART HAL API to transmit 
*   and receive a data buffer with a communication process based on
*   IT transfer. 
*   The communication is done using 2 Boards.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. I used this when reading,receiving data from RS485 with stm32f4zgt.

USART3 Init Commands

```
void RS485Init(USART_TypeDef *Usart, uint32_t BaudRate, uint16_t DataBits, uint16_t Parity, uint16_t StopBits){

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitTypeDef  NVIC_InitStruct;

// Enable clock for GPIOD
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART3, ENABLE); 
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_USART3);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_USART3);
// Initialize pins as alternating function
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);


USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = BaudRate;
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = DataBits;
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = StopBits;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = Parity;
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
USART_Init(USART3, &USART_InitStructure); // USART3-> Usart

NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART3_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct);
USART_Cmd(Usart,ENABLE); 
}
```

Variables

```
char txt_buf[100];
char bin_buf[]={'b','i','n','a','r','y',':',0,1,2,3,4,0x30,0x31,0x32,65,66,67,13,10};
uint16_t tx_len=0;
char *tx_ptr=0;
uint8_t send_ok=1;
```

Buffer and Interrupts Commands

```
void Usart_SendBuf(USART_TypeDef *USART,  uint16_t length, char *buff){
/***********  RS485 DE ve RE pins. **********/
GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_8);
GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_9);
send_ok=0;
tx_len = length; // sending byte count.
// if we'll use string,we don't need this value.
tx_ptr = buff;  // using array address-->> pointer
USART_ITConfig(USART,USART_IT_TXE,ENABLE); // TX  (DR) is empty create an interrupt
}
```

Interrupts

```
void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
if(USART_GetITStatus(USART3,USART_IT_TXE)){
if(--tx_len == 0){ // End of array?
USART_ITConfig(USART3,USART_IT_TXE,DISABLE); // TX flag is unuseful
    USART_ITConfig(USART3,USART_IT_TC,ENABLE); // when sending is ok, create an interr.
    }
    USART_SendData(USART3,(uint16_t) *tx_ptr);
    tx_ptr++;
    USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3,USART_IT_TXE);
}
if(USART_GetITStatus(USART3,USART_IT_TC)){ // Last bit arrived?
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_8);  // take the RS485 mode (take data, buf etc.)
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_9);
    USART_ITConfig(USART3,USART_IT_TC,DISABLE); // all datas is over. We don't need TC Flag
    USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3,USART_IT_TC);
    send_ok=1;
  }
}
```